# Migration N to N using typeOrm

Tags: react-native, expo, typeorm

I'm creating a migration who will create the base tables of my system, but, I have an N to N relation and i don't know will I create it and how to make the typeOrm understand the N to N correctly with the entities

I want to run the migration and make the TypeOrm understand that column A and B will have an N to N relation and make querys using typeOrm API

Comment: actually it is solved [here](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/500761/migrations-de-rela%C3%A7%C3%B5es-manytomany-no-typeorm-usando-queryrunner), thanks.